# How to connect thread to pipes and retrieve that information to another thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, queue, pipe

There are 4 inputs (4 Pipes), and 10 outputs (10 Pipes).
Each one must be read individually and at the same time as the other ones. Each Input Pipe receives Strings that identify containers (it's a program that recreates the processing of the containers in warehouse and then shipped to one of 10 destinations), these strings also contain a serial number and a destination.

The strings have to be processed by each one of the pipes.  They are then put into a single queue (they have to stay there for 1 sec before the processing). They are then sent to a matrix of dimension [n][n] to wait for 1 to 5 secs before being directed to one of the 10 output queues according to the destination (EX: "LND" as London).

For each container in the matrix is created a thread that waits the 1 to 5 secs mentioned before, after that it's put on the output queues. Each queue has a dedicated thread for its processing, and waits 2 secs before writing it to one of the output pipes.

I don't understand how to connect each part (thread to pipe to thread and then to queue etc.).

We tried many different ways to connect the threads to the pipes and write on the files the information needed, but no positive results.

EXAMPLE OF CODE: (here we generate random uuids for each container)

The Code to read the pipe

```
#define MAX_NUM_THREADS 3

void *ler_do_pipe(void *_fd) { //Reads from the pipes
    int fd;
    fd = (int) _fd;
    char buffer[4096];
    int n;
    while ((n = read(fd, buffer, 4096)) > 0) {
        write(1, buffer, n);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[MAX_NUM_THREADS];
    char fifo[5];
    int fd, i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        sprintf(fifo, "fifo%d", i);
        fd = open(fifo, O_RDONLY); 
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, ler_do_pipe, (void *)fd);  
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0; 
}
```

the code I use to write the pipe

```
/*writes to the respective pipe*/
void *escrever_para_pipe(void *_fd) {
    int fd;
    fd = (int) _fd;

    while(1) {
        char txt[43];

        /*criamos uma string do genero "uuid,destino" totalmente random */
    /*we create a string with the "serial Number,destination" all random*/
        sprintf(txt,"%s,%s\n",getuuid(),getPorto());

        write(fd, txt, 43);  
        sleep(2);
    }       
}

int main () {

    //We create 3 threads to the 3 pipes we have
    pthread_t threads[MAX_NUM_THREADS];
    char fifo[5];
    int fd, i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        sprintf(fifo, "fifo%d", i);
        mkfifo(fifo, 0666);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        sprintf(fifo, "fifo%d", i);
        fd = open(fifo, O_WRONLY); 
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, escrever_para_pipe, (void*)fd);  
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that information would flow between pipes and threads but we can't connect them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you want to "connect" a thread to a pipe.  Open files are attributes of a process, not of any individual thread.  Any thread in a process can write to or read from any of that process's open files, as long as it has or can discover the file descriptor number.  The code you present does not help at all, since it exhibits neither multithreading nor pipe usage.

Comment: I'm not sure how to send the information that the thread is done processing to a pipe... Yeah the code here is just an example of how the struct is formed, I'll add more examples right away

Comment: I'm still not understanding.  A pipe is a data conduit, presented as two connected files.  There is a limited number of things you can usefully do with one once you have it, primarily: write data to the write end, read data from read end, or close either or both ends.  Specifically, you can conceivably write information about thread status that can subsequently be read from the other end of the pipe, but if that's what you mean then I don't understand what's stopping you.

Comment: So to read the end of the pipe each thread needs to access that file right? That means the threads have to know which pipe to read from?

Comment: Ok, the revised code helps a little.  It also adds some twists: you have multiple processes involved, not just one, and you're using FIFOs defined on the host filesystem, not pipes created ephemerally via the POSIX `pipe()` function.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying to improve this part before adding the queues and the threads after that send save the information on the matrix.

Comment: Does the question indeed boil down to "That means the threads have to know which pipe to read from"?  In other words, is it conveying thread-specific data to the thread function the problem, so that each thread does the appropriate thing even though they are all running the same function?

Comment: When you construct each thread, why not pass it a pointer to a structure that tells it what it's supposed to be connected to?

Comment: So basically the threads that write on the fifo would have a pointer to which fifo they are going to "connect", and have already threads on the end part to receive the data? Which will then direct the data to where it needs to go

Comment: John Bollinger Yeah if they are all running at the same time, and they try to connect to the same fifo won't it end up in wrong data?